# Common onClick event listener for both button element and RouterLink component in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In below code, the `component` could be either `button`, `input` or `RouterLink`, and we don't know at advance which one will be. I added a lot of attributes to prevent `v-if` solution, because in this case we need to duplicate most of attributes:

```html
<component 
  :is="rootElementTagOrComponentName" 
  @click.prevent="$emit('click', $event.target)"
  :to="route" 
  :type="inputOrButtonElementTypeAttributeValue" 
  :class="CSS_Classes" 
  :value="rootElementTagNameIsInput &amp;&amp; lettering" 
  :role="rootElementIsLink && 'link'" 
  :disabled="(rootElementTagNameIsButton || rootElementTagNameIsInput) &amp;&amp; disabled"
  :ref="ROOT_ELEMENT_REFERENCE"
>
  <template v-if="!rootElementTagNameIsInput && lettering">{{ lettering }}</template>
  <slot v-if="!rootElementTagNameIsInput"></slot>
</component>
```

The `@click.prevent="$emit('click', $event.target)"` not work for `RoterLink`. However, with `@click.native.prevent="$emit('click', $event.target)"` we get

```
[Vue warn]: The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on <button>.
```

How to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

It gets tricky when you have a dynamic component which may or may not be a native element. Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this in the template alone, you'll have to do it in code (`v-on` object syntax does not support native events).

Untested, but something like this may work:

```html
<Root
  :to="route"
  :type="inputOrButtonElementTypeAttributeValue" 
  :class="CSS_Classes" 
  :value="rootElementTagNameIsInput &amp;&amp; lettering" 
  :role="rootElementIsLink && 'link'" 
  :disabled="(rootElementTagNameIsButton || rootElementTagNameIsInput) &amp;&amp; disabled"
  :ref="ROOT_ELEMENT_REFERENCE"
>
  <template v-if="!rootElementTagNameIsInput && lettering">{{ lettering }}</template>
  <slot v-if="!rootElementTagNameIsInput"></slot>
</Root>
```

```js
components: {
  Root: {
    functional: true,

    render(h, ctx) {
      const { data, parent, children } = ctx
      const tag = parent.rootElementTagOrComponentName

      const click = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        parent.$emit('click', e.target)
      }

      if (tag === 'RouterLink') {
        data.nativeOn = data.nativeOn || {}
        data.nativeOn.click = click
      } else {
        data.on = data.on || {}
        data.on.click = click
      }

      return h(tag, data, children)
    }
  }
}
```

All I've done in code is deal with registering the click event, but you could move other things into code as well if you want.